# problem refreshing chromium on Raspberry Pi

Tags: refresh, chromium, pi, kiosk

I am setting up a browser-based kiosk based on a Pi Zero W running chromium.
I would like the browser to refresh every hour to keep it up-to-date with any changes made to the content.
I have followed advice on these forums and have installed xdotool package and set up a shell script (refresh.sh) which works perfectly when run from the cli, containing the following:

sudo -u pi screen -d -m export DISPLAY=:0 && xdotool search "Buckfastleigh Community Noticeboard - Chromium" windowactivate --sync key F5

(where 'Buckfastleigh Community Noticeboard - Chromium' is the name of the browser window that is automatically started on power-on)...

However, when I  make this a cronjob:

sudo crontab -e

...and add:

0 * * * * /home/pi/refresh.sh

...it fails to work. I have no mail client installed so have tried adding a cron error log but there are no error messages being written to it.
Can anyone offer any help?

Many Thanks

Comment: It's possible the crontab job is being ran as the `sudo` user, but when you run the command in your CLI it runs as a different user. Maybe this'll help: https://askubuntu.com/a/505187

Comment: Thanks @JoseSalvatierra - that's what the first bit of the shell script does: sudo -u pi - works when I run it from the CLI logged in as user pi...

Comment: ...have also tried running it from cron as pi user (without the sudo -u pi at the beginning)